# Example of subdirect product of the family of near-ring $S_i$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, semigroups

I am studying a near-ring theory  by $\textbf{Gunter Pilz}$. I want some example of near-ring which is subdirect product of the family of near-ring $S_i$. Secondly i have doubt in the definition of subdirectly irreducible.

- A near-ring $R$ is a subdirect product of a family of near-rings $\{S_i \;:\; i ∈\in I\}$ if there is a monomorphism $k: R \rightarrow S = \underset{i \in I}{\prod} S_i $  such that $\pi_i o k$ is an epimorphism for all $i \in I$, where $\pi_i: S \rightarrow S_i$ is the canonical epimorphism.
- A near-ring $R$ is  called subdirectly irreducible if $R$ is not isomorphic to a non-trivial subdirect product of near-rings.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $F$ be a field.

$F$ is a subdirect product with one factor. Too trivial? Then ...

$F\times F$ is a subdirect product. Not impressed?

$\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty F$ is a nearring without identity, and you can call this ring $R$ or adjoin an identity and call it $R$. Either way $R$ is a subdirect product $R\hookrightarrow \prod_{P\in \mathcal C}R/P$ where $\mathcal C$ is the collection of prime ideals of $R$.

I have no idea what your <s>doubt</s> question is about the definition of subdirectly irreducible nearrings is, since you did not mention it (you just wrote a definition.) The normal definition of a subdirectly irreducible object is that whenever $\phi:R\hookrightarrow \prod_{i\in I}R_i$ is a subdirect product, then $\pi_i\phi$ is an isomorphism for one of the $i$'s.

Comment: firstly Thanks for your answer. Can we conclude that if each factor $R_i$ is trivially subdirect product of $\prod R_i$ and any near-ring $R$ is subdirecctly irreucible iff it is isomorphic to some factor $R_j$.

Comment: No, $R_i$ need not be a subdirect product of $\prod R_i$. For example, there is no injection from $F_2\to F_2\times F_3$ which projects *onto* $F_3$.

Comment: @user120386 I have *no idea* what you mean by $_N\Gamma$.

Comment: @user120386 For rings, the condition of being subdirectly irreducible can be re-expressed as the ring having a unique (nonzero) minimal ideal. I would expect something similar would happen for nearrings. I'm not very familiar with the ideal theory of nearrings so I can't say for certain.

Comment: If $(\Gamma, +)$ is a group and $N$ be a near-ring, then $\Gamma$ is said to be an $N$-group if there is a function $\mu : N \times \Gamma \rightarrow \Gamma$ denoted $\mu ((n,\gamma)) = n \gamma$  with the property $(n + n')\gamma = n\gamma + n' \gamma$ and  $(nn') \gamma = n(n' \gamma)$ and it is denoted by $_N \Gamma$.